# Can I identify my PSN friends which own/play a certain game?

Tags: ps4, psn

I have a PS4 and a PSN account with a few dozen PSN friends.

Is it possible to identify which friends own or play a certain game?

For example is there anywhere I can find out which of my friends play Minecraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the PSN website:

1. [Login to PSN](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/my/account/)
2. Select **My Trophies**
3. Select the game you wish to check
4. Select the **Friends with the Game** button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can view their trophies for different games, and if they have a trophy section for a specific game, they most likely have or have had that game.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that people may choose to hide their trophies for all games, or for a particular game.  Just loading any game adds a trophy list, even if no trophies are received.